# RDP with port forwarding

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to remote on to a windows machine from outside my network with Ubuntu.  I use DynDNS to track the ip address of my router.  The router is set up to use port forwarding.  From a Windows machine I can use companyname.ath.cx:PortNumber.  But I can't get this to work from Remmina.  I have tried using my current router ip and the port number (e.g. 123.456.789.11:1234) but no luck.

Any ideas please.
Thanks - Peter

Comment: It works perfectly well from a Windows machine using RDP outside my network so why is it not a Remmina issue or am I missing something.

Comment: You don't give any details about errors, etc. you see, you need to *start* by providing that information.

Comment: What is the output of `nc -v companyname.ath.cx PortNumber`

Comment: Or if you have *nmap* installed: `nmap -Pn -sV  companyname.ath.cx  -p PortNumber`

Comment: The nc command was successful.  After a few more tries with Remmina, replacing the colon before the port number with a space and then putting it back it works perfectly.  I guess I had some syntax wrong.  Thanks all.